# How to keep track of employer for transfers TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created a sproc named empTransfers that should return all employees who have been transferred over a period of time (this being tracked by two params).

In the sample code I have provided below the sproc does give me every transfer. However, it only return the latest previous employer and I can't keep track of every previous employer once the person has been transferred more than once.

I would truly appreciate some insight as to how I can keep track of all previous employers for a person who has been transferred multiple times over the specified timeframe.

**GetEmpl is a function that gets the employer ID given the employee ID and date

```
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[HumanResource_getEmpTransfers]

--(  
    @spBeginDate DATE ,
    @spEndDate DATE
--)
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;



        SELECT  * ,
                CITO.dbo.getEmpl(main.emp_id,
                                 ( SELECT   ( SELECT    MAX(ee.next_eff_date)
                                            ) AS date_transfered
                                   FROM     DBShrpn..emp_employment AS ee
                                   WHERE    ee.next_eff_date <> '2999-12-31'
                                            AND ee.emp_id = main.emp_id
                                 )) AS previous_employer
        FROM    ( SELECT    e.emp_display_name ,
                            ee.empl_id ,
                            ( SELECT    MAX(ee.eff_date)
                            ) AS date_transfered ,
                            ee.emp_id
                  FROM      DBShrpn..emp_employment AS ee
                            INNER JOIN DBShrpn..employee AS e ON e.emp_id = ee.emp_id
                  WHERE     ee.next_eff_date <> '2999-12-31'
    --and ee.emp_id = '000113609'   
    --and ee.emp_id = '000421424'       
                  GROUP BY  ee.empl_id ,
                            ee.emp_id ,
                            e.emp_display_name
                  UNION
                  SELECT    e.emp_display_name ,
                            ee.empl_id ,
                            ( SELECT    MAX(ee.eff_date)
                            ) AS date_transfered ,
                            ee.emp_id
                  FROM      DBShrpn..emp_employment AS ee
                            INNER JOIN DBShrpn..employee AS e ON ee.emp_id = e.emp_id
                  WHERE     ee.next_eff_date = '2999-12-31'
    --and ee.emp_id = '000113609'       
    --and ee.emp_id = '000421424'       
                  GROUP BY  ee.empl_id ,
                            ee.emp_id ,
                            e.emp_display_name
                ) AS main
        WHERE   main.date_transfered >= @spBeginDate
                AND main.date_transfered <= @spEndDate
                AND main.empl_id <> CITO.dbo.getEmpl(main.emp_id,
                                                     ( SELECT ( SELECT
                                                              MAX(ee.next_eff_date)
                                                              ) AS date_transfered
                                                       FROM   DBShrpn..emp_employment
                                                              AS ee
                                                       WHERE  ee.next_eff_date <> '2999-12-31'
                                                              AND ee.emp_id = main.emp_id
                                                     ))
        ORDER BY main.emp_display_name ,
                main.previous_employer ASC  
    END
```

Comment: Since you are only using the MAX(ee.eff_date) then you will only get the last employer.  You could probably change it to look for ee.eff_date within your timeline and pull back all transfers for that employee and then deal with the multiple records being returned (unless you were attempting to pivot all of the previous employers into some sort of delimited column)

Comment: in your where clause `main.empl_id <> CITO.dbo.getEmpl` doesn't make sense because it seems like you are filtering the previous employers since they would be returned by your inner select statements that you have unioned together. why are you doing that? (also it might help to have sample data -- here's a sqlfiddle that you can play with a little to show ppl what you have: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/70f09/4)